# Highcharts Line Chart Time Durations

Tags: time, highcharts, duration

I have just started to use Highcharts and am a little stuck.

I need to plot a line chart with People and time duration. I have edited some code i found online and have the following:

```
    $(function () {
    // Call Times
    $('#TotalCallDuration').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: '',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Person 1','Person 2','Person 3','Person 4','Person 5','Person 6','Person 7','Person 8','Person 9','Person 10','Person 11',]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total Call Duration'
            },
            type: 'time',
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    var time = this.value;
                    var hours1=parseInt(time/3600000);
                    var mins1=parseInt((parseInt(time%3600000))/60000);
                    return (hours1 < 10 ? '0' + hours1 : hours1) + ':' + (mins1 < 10 ? '0' + mins1 : mins1);
                }   
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [7464000,4327000,3388000,3611000,3261000,5740000,9433000,8591000,8114000,3059000,10866000],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                formatter: function () {
                    var time = this.y / 1000;
                    //var time = this.y;
                    var hours1=parseInt(time/3600);
                    var mins1=parseInt((parseInt(time%3600))/60);
                    return (hours1 < 10 ? '0' + hours1 : hours1) + ':' + (mins1 < 10 ? '0' + mins1 : mins1);
                }
            },
        }]
    });
});
```

I have also created https://jsfiddle.net/MarcellusWallis/jnp6xodk/

However, i also want to display the seconds as at the moment im only displaying the HH:MM.

Also when i hover over the line i get the legend popup but its display in milliseconds and not HH:MM:SS

Comment: One question to clarify what you're asking: are the data you've included in this sample (7464000, 4327000, 3388000, etc.) in milliseconds?

Comment: I think so, its a thousand times a second.

Comment: Its an example that i am editing

Comment: OK, I just wanted to be certain, as 7464000 milliseconds = 7464 seconds. That seemed really high for a call volume chart.

Answer (score 2):

To change format in yAxis labels you could use [`dateTimeLabelFormats`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats) and for tooltip you could use [`pointFormat`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.pointFormat) and set your format there.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/s6t8ghvu/

Relevant code:

```
yAxis: {
  title: {
    text: 'Total Call Duration'
  },
  type: 'datetime',
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    minute: '%H:%M:%S'
  }
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y: %H:%M:%S}</b><br/>'
},
```

Comment: This is working perfectly, however if i slightly change the dataset to: data: [2403000,2701000,1887000,4746000,7464000,8904000,8294000,6926000,9718000,3920000,3618000,1604000], the first character on the vertical axis should be 00:00:00 but is displaying as 1. Jan

Comment: @user1315422 It's a date-time format for day, so you could override that format in `dateTimeLabelFromats` using `day` - example: https://jsfiddle.net/s6t8ghvu/1/